# creating token on solana blockchain

Tags: token, help

Created token on solana blockchain using tutorial on internet but then seen this message that solana repo is closed and have to find another way to create token.
It says :
"Adding a New Token
You can use one of two tools at the time of writing:

Strata Protocol Token Launchpad - https://app.strataprotocol.com/launchpad/manual/new
Token Creator Demo - [https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/"](https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/%22)

Is that actual? it says powered by Solana on second link. Is it a scam or is it actually working those both tools?

please help ^^

Answer (score 1):

This is the actual token creator, not a scam
Token Creator Demo - [https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/"](https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/%22)